# Face Recognition with PHP?

Tags: php

iam playing around with OPEN CV from Intel with the associated PHP Extensions. Works like a charm. But does someone knows as way to do Face Recognition instead of only Face Detection with PHP?

Iam not sure if someone has tryed it so far, or if it is impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its good possible but youve got a problem with php because its short execution time.
the most easy way is to just execute a program that does the reconition and than return the results, like:

```
<?php
echo exec('facesearch image.jpg');
?>
```

An other way is to make your own extention for php but this is a lot harder

Answer (score 1):

Sure it's possible.

You "just" have to write the mind blastingly complex algorithms for it yourself or find a library that already does it.

It's not a problem of PHP. It's the same as in every other language.

Although I'd recommend a language/runtime that is more efficient in terms of pure calculation speed, like C++ maybe.